# Deserialize breadth-first trees

Tags: algorithm, clojure, tree

I need to work with quad-trees as follows:

```
           p
         /| |\ 
        / | | \    
       /  | |  \
      p   w b   p
    /| |\     /| |\   
   / | | \   / | | \
  b  w w  b w  b w  b
```

But they have been serialized to a string using breadth-first order, so the previous tree would have the following representation:

`ppwbpbwwbwbwb`

I'm trying to transform such a string to a nested vector structure:

`[ [ b w w b ] w b [ w b w b] ]`

But sometimes the following code doesn't work correctly:

```
(defn read-quad-tree [pattern]
  (loop [r                    []
         [s & rs :as stack]   []
         [p & rp :as pending] (reverse pattern)]
    (cond (nil? pending)  (first r)
          (= (count r) 4) (recur [] (conj stack (reverse r)) pending)
          (= p \p)        (recur (conj r s) rs rp)
          :else           (recur (conj r p) stack rp))))
```

**Edited for adding a complex example:**

Another (failed) example. The next tree:

```
                    |
         +------+-------+------+
         |      |       |      |
         |      w       w      |
         |                     |
   +---+---+---+         +---+---+---+
   |   |   |   |         |   |   |   | 
   |   w   w   |         |   w   w   |
   |           |         |           |
+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+   +-+-+-+     +-+-+-+
| | | |     | | | |   | | | |     | | | |
b b b b     w w w w   b b w w     b w b w
```

will be serialized as:

`ppwwppwwppwwpbbbbwwwwbbwwbwbw`

and the goal is to get the following structure:

`[ [ [ b b b b ] w w [ w w w w ] ] w w [ [ b b w w ] w w [ b w b w ] ] ]`

But my code gives a different (wrong) structure.

Comment: Is there a rule that children always belong to a `p` parent and all other letters are leaves of the tree?

Comment: Yes, the leaf nodes always are `b` or `w`, and the `p` is used in the serialization to indicate that node has childrens.

Comment: This would be a good use case for a round-trip test with [test.check](https://github.com/clojure/test.check).

Comment: It appears that the code provided works with the data given. Please edit your question and include at least one example where the code you've posted does not produce the desired output. If you would, please include a diagram of the tree in quad-tree form, the serialized version of the tree, the expected results, and the results you're getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code suffers from some names representing lists instead of (intended) vectors.

This can already been seen from the function's return value, which is a list.

Look at these parts of the code:

```
(loop   ...
        [s & rs :as stack]
        ...
        (recur (conj r s) rs rp)
```

The highlighted `[s & rs :as stack]` will get the *stack* vector, name the first element *s* and the remaining elements as **list**(!) *rs*. As *rs* is a list, it will at some point pass on like that to *stack* (via the last `recur`), which then also is a list, and not a vector. Then, the next time *r* has 4 elements, `(conj stack ...` will not append *r*, but prefix it, as that is the behaviour of `conj` when applied to lists. Quoted from the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj):

> ;; notice that conjoining to a vector is done at the end
>
> ;; notice conjoining to a list is done at the beginning

This, of course, destroys the intended algorithm, and explains the wrong results you get.

A similar problem occurs with `(reverse r)` which [returns a seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reverse), even though *r* is a vector.

You can fix it, for instance, by applying `(into [] ...)` where you want lists to be passed on as vectors. I see two spots where you need to do this:

```
(defn read-quad-tree [pattern]
  (loop [r                    []
         [s & rs :as stack]   []
         [p & rp :as pending] (reverse pattern)]
    (cond (nil? pending)  (first r)
          (= (count r) 4) (recur [] (conj stack (into [] (reverse r))) pending)
          (= p \p)        (recur (conj r s) (into [] rs) rp)
          :else           (recur (conj r p) stack rp))))
```

The fix is not needed for *pending*, as it never "infects" the other names with the list type.

When the corrected code is called like this:

```
(println (read-quad-tree "ppwwppwwppwwpbbbbwwwwbbwwbwbw"))
```

it will output:

```
[[[b b b b] w w [w w w w]] w w [[b b w w] w w [b w b w]]]
```

While looking for the problem, I also added some checks on (in)valid patterns, which might interest you. The extended code is as follows:

```
(defn read-quad-tree [pattern]
    (loop   [r                   []
            [s & rs :as stack]   []
            [p & rp :as pending] (reverse pattern)]
        (cond
            (nil? pending)
                (if (or (seq stack) (not= (count r) 1))
                    {:error "Too few 'p'"}
                    {:tree (first r)})
            (= (count r) 4)
                (recur [] (conj stack (into [] (reverse r))) pending)
            (= p \p) 
                (if (empty? s)
                    {:error (format "'p' at %s lacks %d children" (count pending) (- 4 (count r)))}
                    (recur (conj r s) (into [] rs) rp))
            :else
                (recur (conj r p) stack rp))))
```

It will return a map with a *tree* key if all goes well, or with an *error* key if the pattern is incomplete.